# UIButton in a view based application

Tags: uiview, xcode4, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

This is a view-based application

i have a button in the ViewController.m 
Added a new subview controller class and trying to open the new view when the button is clicked.

Code :

```
- (IBAction) accessByProducts: (id) sender {  

    if(self.accessByProducts == nil) {
        AccessByProducts *acb = [[AccessByProducts alloc] initWithNibName:@"AccessByProducts" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.accessByProducts = acb;
        [acb release];
    }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to open up . can anyone help me or guide me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(self.accessByProducts == nil) {
    AccessByProducts *acb = [[AccessByProducts alloc] initWithNibName:@"AccessByProducts" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.accessByProducts = acb;
    [self.view addSubview:acb.view];  //add as sub view
    [acb release];
}
```

Also, what type is your self.accessByProducts and does it do anything more than just keeping a reference?